# Stream video from camera behind NAT to public access server

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, nat

Imagine this scenario:

1. We have a publicly accessible server on which we can install any software. Or we have AWS account from where we can use any AWS service.
2. We have multiple devices installed in different networks, all separately behind NAT.
3. All of this devices stores and live-streams video.
4. I cannot connect directly to any of this devices because of random IP and non-forwarded ports that I cannot access.
5. I can connect from the device to the publicly accessible server.

How can I access video stream (HLS) from any selected device in the world connecting publicly accessible server?

---

I cannot use things like http://live555.com/proxyServer/ because I cannot select backend URL.

Answer (score 0):

Potential options:

- configure the NAT in question to forward the port in question
- modify the devices (e.g. via custom firmware) to connect to the server
- install a relay server in the same network as the devices which forwards the stream to the server
- look for alternative devices that support your usecase
- use IPv6

Comment: There are very few solutions that allows devices to connect to the server to stream. This always works other way round. Any known solutions? Only single I can think of is `ffmpeg -listen 1`.